# USB-C male to USB-A female data transfer: connecting a USB-C flash drive to a computer with a USB-A port

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB-C flash drive and I'd like to access the data on it using a laptop with an USB-A 3.0 port (a Surface Pro 4). https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung/posts/UFCHbSDRa2o seems to be saying that it is impossible to have a compliant USB-A female to USB-C male adapter cable, and Leung comments that this product is non-compliant: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B019HWA79A/ref=psdc_464394_t1_B011NNGX9O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019HWA79A)

What is the best way to use a USB-C flash drive from a laptop with USB-A port (short of using another computer with a USB-C port, obviously)?

Comment: Hardware recommendations are not on topic, so asking for a specific model, is going to be taken as a hardware request

Comment: No, this is a request about forward compatibility between older Type-A host and newer Type-C plug.

Comment: @Ramhound The question sounds pretty general to me, not specific. It is about whether a conversion between USB 3.1 Type C and USB type A will work.

Comment: @yoyo_fun, saying "USB 3.1 Type-C" is not sufficient to describe/define the problem. You should differentiate between USB Type-C receptacle, and USB Type-C male plug. The plug has no intelligence to determine connect polarity. All Type-C intelligence is built into C-receptacle. The flash drive is essentially a male plug, and proper connection would require an intelligent C-receptacle, which Type-A port does not have. That's why there is a problem, and questions arise.

Comment: @AliChen the question literally wanted a list of hardware that was compatible.

Comment: @Ramhound , no, I strongly disagree. This is a fundamental backward compatibility issue that has no easy solution. As the question fixed by fixer1234 (as I can see now, 19 hrs ago), it has very broad implications.

Comment: My comment was before the question was edited.

Answer (score 2):

The female-Type-A legacy cable to male Type-C is a legal cable assembly, per spec. I think it is a misprint in the question.

However, adapting the new Type-C device plug to legacy Type-A host port is indeed a challenge, and it is not addressed by specifications. Although there are Type-A receptacle to Type-C plug adapter dongles (as referenced in the question), they cannot provide one of main benefit of Type-C connector, the universal polarity of it. The other problem is that the simple passive dongle will provide always-on VBUS, which is against Type-C mode of operation. Other than that, they should work if nicely implemented, you just would need to flip the Type-C connection in 50% cases to get USB 3 speeds, and the USB2 should always work.

The right way to connect a Type-C flash drive to a legacy Type-A host port is to use a proper hub, with legacy type (A or B) of connector upstream, and full-blown **Type-C receptacles on downstream ports**. Recently Genesys Logic announced such hub controller chip, [GL3523S](http://www.genesyslogic.com/en/product_view.php?show=55), as well as others like Microchip and Cypress, but at this time it is difficult to find any OEM products with these chips yet, only [development boards are available](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DT-USB5734). If you should find a finished OEM product of this kind, please post.

Comment: Actually, a passive adapter switch from Type-C port to legacy Type-A port is feasible too, but it would require an active Type-C-compliant polarity management logic, and a high-speed analog multiplexer. I doubt that these kind of dongles exist, they must be too costly to make.

Comment: I upvoted the answer.  A couple of suggestions to make it even better. 1) Add a sentence or two to the middle paragraph explaining the flip issue (what the problem is and why).  2) The hub solution in the last paragraph--it sounds like you're saying that this is a theoretical solution; you aren't aware of an existing product?  So the bottom line is that the only current OTS solution is an adapter, and you may need to flip the connector if it doesn't work?  If that's a correct reading, you might want to highlight the actual solution so it isn't lost in the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks. I added a clarification about flips, and provided a link to a demo board as a possible legal solution, instead of illegal dongle. If OP will use the dongle only as an adapter to his flash drive and will not attempt to experiment with some arbitrary connectivity, there is no harm.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question with a new solution.  In the last few months Other World Computing released a USB4/Thunderbolt hub.  https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB4HUB5P/

This is not a recommendation for this specific product but OWC has the only examples I've seen on the market so far.  I'm not affiliated with OWC other than buying their gear.  I've used this hub to add USB-C ports to a MacBook that lacks USB-C ports.  It works by using a standard USB-A/male to USB-C/male cable to connect the laptop to the upstream USB-C port on the hub.  As far as I can tell all USB ports on the hub are fully functional.

The reason these products did not exist until very recently is that until USB4, published in 2019, the USB spec did not define how hubs with multiple USB-C ports were supposed to work.  It takes time to ramp up production of devices to a new spec so that is part of the delay.  There's no doubt that some fly-by-night electronics manufacturers built USB-C hubs but they were often fire hazards and always behaved oddly.

There must be other products like this by now, just verify it meets the USB4 spec before you buy.  This is not exactly a low cost solution but it is the only kind of solution that is within the USB spec.